# Calculating the next available date for an employee using DAX in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have the following table

```
Date     |        assignee        |        TotalLoad (%)

01.01.2023       employee_X                125
01.01.2023       employee_X                75
01.01.2023       employee_X                25
.
.
.
31.12.2023       employee_X                50

01.01.2023       employee_Y                125
01.01.2023       employee_Y                75
01.01.2023       employee_Y                50
.
.
.
31.12.2023       employee_Y                50
```

I want to write a measure finds the next date, in which an employee will be available (Load < 100)

So far I tried this:

```
Next Available Day = 
VAR CurrentEmployee = SELECTEDVALUE('employees_daily_load'[assignee])
VAR CurrentDate = SELECTEDVALUE('employees_daily_load'[Date])
VAR NextAvailableDay =
CALCULATE(
    MIN(employees_daily_load[Date]),
    FILTER(employees_daily_load,
    'employees_daily_load'[assignee] = CurrentEmployee &&
    'employees_daily_load'[TotalAssignedUnitsforDay] <= 50 &&
    'employees_daily_load'[Date] > CurrentDate
    )
)
RETURN NextAvailableDay
```

and this:

```
Next Available Day = 
VAR CurrentEmployee = SELECTEDVALUE('employees_daily_load'[assignee])
VAR CurrentDate = SELECTEDVALUE('employees_daily_load'[Date])
VAR NextAvailableDay =
CALCULATE(
    MIN(employees_daily_load[Date]),
    FILTER(employees_daily_load,
    'employees_daily_load'[assignee] = CurrentEmployee &&
    'employees_daily_load'[TotalAssignedUnitsforDay] <= 50 &&
    'employees_daily_load'[Date] > CurrentDate
    )
)
RETURN NextAvailableDay
```

but it returns always 01.01.2023 (the first date) for all employees. I am still beginner in DAX and powerBI that is why I can not understand where the problem lies. I use PowerBI Desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correct, you are looking for a measure like below-

```
Measure = 
CALCULATE(
    min(your_tab_name[Date]),
    FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT(your_tab_name,your_tab_name[assignee]),
        your_tab_name[Date] > min(your_tab_name[Date])
            && your_tab_name[TotalLoad (%)] <= 50
    )
)
```

OUtput will be like below-

[image]

Comment: Hello, I solved it using this something similar: 
`Next Available Day = 
VAR CurrentEmp = SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[assignee])
VAR CurrentDate = SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Date])
VAR NextAvailableDay =
CALCULATE(
    MIN(Table[Date]),
    FILTER(Table,
    'Table'[assignee] = CurrentEmployee &&
    'Table'[Load] < 100 &&
    'Table'[Date] > CurrentDate
    )
)
RETURN NextAvailableDay`

your code did not work because I think it does not filter the assignee and the date as per the view context. not sure though. your feedback?

Comment: You did the same I did in the measure. Except just conditions are different.